# training neural network using genetic algorithm

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm, backpropagation

I have an optimisation problem where the objective function I want to maximise is not differentiable. I've trained a linear model using genetic algorithm, but the performance the linear model is not that good. I am thinking about replacing the linear model with a neural network. But my understanding is that with a non-differentiable objective function I cannot use the backprop method to do updates.
So, does anyone know how to use the genetic algorithm to train a neural network?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is called neuro-evolution. If you are good at programming, you could make your own [NEAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution_of_augmenting_topologies) (neuroevolution of augmenting topologies) implementation. However, there are already a lot of implementations out there.

If you want to play around with neuroevolution first, you might want to check out [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic). All you need to do is set up the network and run a single function to get the neuroevolution started.

Comment: Can you suggest any implementations or examples I should look at?@Thomas W

Comment: @ascetic652 well [here](https://github.com/wagenaartje/agario-ai) for example Neataptic is used to evolve genomes to play agario